# How to use an input number in a child component in Vue.JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a project in which currently, I can create draggable divs by clicking on a button. Now, I want to be able to change the size of these divs with an input.
My problem is that I don't know how to do this.
Could you help me ?

First, here is my App.vue:

```
<template>
<div id = 'dd'>
  <div>
    <input type = "Number" v-model="length" placeholder="Longueur de la boîte">
    <input type = "Number" v-model="width" placeholder="Largeur de la boîte">

    <Bouton @clic-bouton="apply" text="Appliquer" color='pink'></Bouton>
  </div>
  <Bouton @clic-bouton="addDraggableDiv" text="Ajouter" color="cyan"></Bouton>

  <DraggableDiv class="col-11" v-for = "index in count" :key="index">
    <template>

    </template>
  </DraggableDiv>
</div>


</template>

<script>
import DraggableDiv from './components/DraggableDiv.vue'
import Bouton from './components/Bouton.vue'


export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return{
      count : 1,
      length : 240,
      width : 156,
    }
  },
  components: {
    DraggableDiv,
    Bouton,
  },
  methods:{
  addDraggableDiv(){
      this.count+=1
  },

}
}
</script>

<style>


</style>
```

And then, here is my DraggableDiv.vue that I want to update with inputs:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div ref="draggableContainer" id="draggable-container" @mousedown="dragMouseDown" :style='taille'>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import App from "../App.vue"

export default {
  name: 'DraggableDiv',
  data: function () {
    return {
      positions: {
        clientX: undefined,
        clientY: undefined,
        movementX: 0,
        movementY: 0,
        App
      }
    }
  },
  props:{
    length : {
      type: Number,
    },
    width : {
      type: Number,
    }
    },
    computed :{
      taille(){
        return{
          '--longueur': this.length + 'px',
          '--largeur': this.width + 'px'
        }
      }
    },
  methods: {
    dragMouseDown: function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
      this.positions.clientX = event.clientX
      this.positions.clientY = event.clientY
      document.onmousemove = this.elementDrag
      document.onmouseup = this.closeDragElement
    },
    elementDrag: function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      this.positions.movementX = this.positions.clientX - event.clientX
      this.positions.movementY = this.positions.clientY - event.clientY
      this.positions.clientX = event.clientX
      this.positions.clientY = event.clientY
      // set the element's new position:
      this.$refs.draggableContainer.style.top = (this.$refs.draggableContainer.offsetTop - this.positions.movementY) + 'px'
      this.$refs.draggableContainer.style.left = (this.$refs.draggableContainer.offsetLeft - this.positions.movementX) + 'px'
    },
    closeDragElement () {
      document.onmouseup = null
      document.onmousemove = null
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#draggable-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  height: var(--longueur);
  width: var(--largeur);
  background-color: rgb(170, 104, 43);
  border-color: black;
  border: 2px solid;
}

</style>
```

As you can see I have tried some things with props and computed props but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, if you are working with numbers and input its good to use the [`.number` prefix](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) like: `type= "Number" v-model.number="length"`. To edit the dimensions you only need to change the height and width of the div element. Like `this.$refs.draggableContainer.style.height = NEW PX VALUE`

Comment: @wittgenstein i tried adding a onclick dunction named apply which contains         this.$refs.draggableContainer.style.height = NEW PX VALUE but it doesn't work, I receive an error message saying that I can't read property style of undefined

Comment: the NEW PX VALUE means your new pixel values, like `158px` or `268px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not far off from working.

`v-model` binds values as strings by default, but you can use the `vmodel.number` modifier to automically bind a `Number` value (as pointed out in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158143/how-to-use-an-input-number-in-a-child-component-in-vue-js#comment118708860_67158143)):

```html
<input type="Number" v-model.number="length" placeholder="Longueur de la boîte" />
                               
<input type="Number" v-model.number="width" placeholder="Largeur de la boîte" />
```

Then you'll need to bind those properties to `<DraggableDiv>`:

```html
<DraggableDiv :length="length" :width="width" />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/binding-numbers-to-v-model-kjg0x?file=/src/App.vue)